# Fast dataframe normalization in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization

In Python/Pandas, I am trying to normalize all numeric columns of a dataframe to counts per million using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
def normalize(df):
    numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
    numeric_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype in numerics]
    sums = df.sum(axis=0, skipna = True)
    for col in numeric_cols:
        df.insert(df.columns.get_loc(col)+1, col+'_norm', ((df[col]/sums[col])*1000000)+1)
    return df
dataset = pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col=['Guide1', 'Guide2'], sep=',')
dataset = normalize(dataset)
```

This is a short example input:

```
Guide1,Guide2,Gene1,Gene2,NHT1,NHT2,hart_essential_1,hart_essential_2,lib,RPE1_n1,RPE1_n2,RPE1_n3
Gene_1-KO-3,Non-Human-Target-150-KO-26,Gene_1,Non-Human-Target-150,False,True,False,False,12426.0,10634.0,8701.0,8084.0
Gene_2-KO-3,Non-Human-Target-150-KO-26,Gene_2,Non-Human-Target-150,False,True,False,False,12300.0,12383.0,6252.0,5388.0
Gene_1-KO-3,Gene_4-KO-2,Gene_1,Gene_4,False,False,False,False,11685.0,10006.0,10621.0,7002.0
Gene_1-KO-3,Gene_5-KO-2,Gene_1,Gene_5,False,False,False,False,11347.0,6726.0,3927.0,3943.0
Gene_1-KO-3,Gene_6-KO-1,Gene_1,Gene_6,False,False,False,False,11250.0,12469.0,3552.0,3334.0
```

The code works as intended and normalizes all numeric columns of that dataframe, but it seems to work very slow, also with other normalization methods. I am regularly working with dataframes that contain up to several millions of rows. For ~1 million rows and only 4 numeric columns, normalization takes almost 10 minutes on my mobile computer with an Intel Core i7-6600U @ 2.6GHz, although I precompute the sums for every column.
Is there a way to speed this up, e.g., parallelization or some neat Pandas trick?

Any help and/or pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: Do you wish to add new colmns or replace them with the normalized value?

Comment: I would like to add new columns and keep the raw data.

Comment: Can you give us a small sample input?

Comment: @Horbaje I added a small example input, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for taking time to answer me! I came up with another solution that I would like to share. [YaoYao](http://yaoyao.codes/pandas/2018/01/23/pandas-split-a-dataframe-into-chunks) inspired me to test the multiprocessing library to tackle my problem. The following solution runs extremely fast. The script starts by reading the .csv file, determines the names of the numeric columns and computes their sums. Then it splits the dataset into equally sized chunks and maps the normalizing function to each chunk. The resulting normalized dataframes are concatenated back to yield the entire normalized dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def index_marks(nrows, chunk_size):
    return range(chunk_size, math.ceil(nrows / chunk_size) * chunk_size, chunk_size)

def split(dfm, chunk_size):
    indices = index_marks(dfm.shape[0], chunk_size)
    return np.split(dfm, indices)

def normalize(df, sums, numeric_cols):
    for col in numeric_cols:
        df.insert(df.columns.get_loc(col)+1, col+'_norm', ((df[col]/sums[col])*1000000)+1)
    return df

def parallel_normalize(data):
    df = data[0]
    sums = data[1]
    numeric_cols = data[2]

    df = normalize(df, sums, numeric_cols)
    return df

numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
dataset_file = '/path/to/file.csv'

cores = 3

dataset = pd.read_csv(dataset_file, index_col=['Guide1', 'Guide2'], sep=',')
dataset = dataset.fillna(0.0)

numeric_cols = [col for col in dataset.columns if dataset[col].dtype in numerics]
sums = dataset[numeric_cols].sum(axis=0, skipna = True)

chunks = split(dataset, int(round(dataset.shape[0]/cores)))
pool = Pool(cores)
dataset = pd.concat(pool.map(parallel_normalize, [[x, sums, numeric_cols] for x in chunks]))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I do not know why the speedup is that enormous, though. I would have expected a speedup of maybe 60%, because I split the data into 3 chunks. But it literally runs instantaneously. If anyone could comment and give some insight here, I'd be more than happy!

Answer (score 0):

The normalization in this adaptation of your code is pretty much instantaneous. Most of the time is spent generating those random numbers...

```
import pandas as pd
import random

numeric_dtypes = {'int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64'}

# Generate data...
n = 1000000
floats = [random.uniform(0, 100000) for x in range(n)]
ints = [int(i) for i in floats]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for dtype in numeric_dtypes:
    df[dtype] = pd.Series((ints if 'int' in dtype else floats), dtype=dtype)

# Normalize...
sums = df.sum(axis=0, skipna=True)
for col in df.columns:
    if str(df[col].dtype) not in numeric_dtypes:
        continue
    df[col + "_norm"] = df[col] / sums[col] * 1000000 + 1

print(df)
```